# Forwarded domain not working with https

Tags: https, dns, forwarding

I had an old web site: https://oldsite.com. I created a new site on a different web server: https://newsite.com

I forwarded the domain oldsite.com to newsite.com. The problem is that when https://oldsite.com is entered, I get a site cannot be found message. It redirects fine when entered with just http, but breaks down on the https.

How can I go about forwarding both the http and the https to a the new site?

Thank you?

Comment: Can you explain how you forwarded your old domain? I'm _guessing_ that it's a DNS CNAME record based on the `dns` tag, but not 100% sure.

Comment: RomanK, at the domain registrar, I set it up to forward to the new site.

Comment: This must be DNS then. In that case, HTTP and HTTPs should behave the same. Are you sure that https://newsite.com works when you access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

try  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.newsite.com/newurl.html">`

this will just use the meta in your site to redirect it to your new site.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I add this to the old site? If yes, I should have mentioned, the old site doesn't exist any more. If that's not what you're suggesting, can you please clarify? Thank you!

Comment: Yes thats what i was suggesting. But if the site doesnt exist anymore you can use dns tot redirect it